# Parsing Multiple Tags From HTML via Applescript

Tags: applescript

If I want to pull all the actors' names, I tried this, but it only pulls one name. Is there a repeat loop or anything else I can do to have it pull all the tags that say `<span itemprop="name">`?

```
set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters

set startHere to "<span itemprop=\"name\">"
set stopHere to "</span>"
set mysource_html to do shell script "curl https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=H9EKG4-JHSw"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startHere
set blurb1 to text item 2 of mysource_html
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to stopHere
set blurb2 to text item 1 of blurb1

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {"<td class=\"credit-label\">Actors</td>", "<td class=\"credit-label\">Producers</td>"}}
set mysource_html to text item 2 of (do shell script "curl https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=H9EKG4-JHSw")
set text item delimiters to TID

set mysource_html to every paragraph of (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of mysource_html & " | grep -Eo '<span itemprop=\"name\">[^<]*' | sed 's/.*>//g'")
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this again, but doing that gets me the directors and producers as well. If I only wanted it to get me actors, is there a way to further grep that?